# Get least sum of a combination of matrix elements

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, math, matrix

Yesterday one of my friend came with a problem, asking me to find the solution.

**The problem**

I have a `matrix(n x m)`. I need to find out the least sum what I can produce from those matrix element.

The condition is :

- Counting should only start from the top left cell. And
- Should end at the bottom right cell.
- The algorithm should count all possible paths
- In this way I need to find the possible least sum.

After struggling for a few hours, I'm able to find a pattern for this. But I don't know how to implement it in code.

Here is my pattern :

[image]

How can I implement this?

**Edit :**

```
$Cost = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < $rows; $x++) {
    $Cost[0][$x] = $matrix[0][$x];
    for ($y = 1; $y < $cols; $y++) {
        $Cost[$y][0] = $matrix[$y][0];
    }
}
for ($x = 1; $x < $rows; $x++) {
    for ($y = 1; $y < $cols; $y++) {
        $Cost[$x][$y] = intval($matrix[$x][$y]) + min(intval($Cost[$x - 1][$y]), intval($Cost[$x][$y - 1]));
    }
}
```

Matrix array I'm Trying :

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(2) "44" [2]=> string(2) "75" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "21" [1]=> string(2) "98" [2]=> string(2) "60" } }
```

Result :

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(2) "44" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "21" [1]=> int(119) [2]=> int(0) } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> NULL } }
```

Comment: Reformulate as shortest path problem and apply Dijkstra A*. Edge length is sum of cell values

Comment: This is a path finding problem - there are several useful algorithms for something like this (A* and its variants being a good start)

Comment: If the matrix will always be ordered like that, then the last path would always be the smallest.

Comment: @SecondRikudo Matrix will never ordered like that. I just created a sample. It will be in any format

Comment: Sure, just pointing it out :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you can go only in right and down directions. For this case *(otherwise use path finding algorithms)* note that you can come in every cell either from upper cell or from left cell. The cheapest path to this cell will be minimum from these values. So DP solution may look like (pseudocode):

**see corrections here**

```
Cost[0, 0] = matrix[0, 0]  
for x = 1 to cols - 1 
   Cost[0, x] = matrix[0, x] + Cost[0, x-1]  //0th row
for y = 1 to rows - 1  
   Cost[y, 0] = matrix[y, 0] + Cost[y-1, 0] //0th column
//proper filling of 0th row and 0th column

for y = 1 to rows - 1
   for x = 1 to cols - 1 
      Cost[y, x] = matrix[y, x] + Min(Cost[y-1, x], Cost[y, x-1])
```

then Cost[n-1, n-1] is what you need

Comment: Exactly. Just also add the parent so that you can reconstruct the solution.

Comment: @Second Rikudo Should I add a dozen of '$' everywhere to make this pseudocode PHP-readable? :-)

Comment: No, but you should indicate that it's pseudo code :)

Comment: @MBo Your solution is not working. See edited question. It gives `21`, Required is `182`

Comment: You have forgotten my remark about edge cells - look at expanded pseudocode now

Comment: Another possible issue in your code - I suspect that for cycles should look like  ($x = 0; $x < $rows; $x++)   (deleted '-1')

Comment: @MBo again it is not giving the result.

Comment: Be careful - you are mixing up both $Cost[$y][$x] and $Cost[$x][$y] indexation... And two first cycles should be separated (not an error, just excessive work).

Comment: @MBo I'm not mixing those. See the edit in the question code is same as your `pseudocode` (And why you are using `n` for both `rows` and `columns`, bit confusing ).

Comment: I've seen my mistake in edge cells filling. Corrected

Answer (score 1):

An update to **MBo**'s answer. Given a n*m (n=3, m=4 in your post) The space consumed can be reduce to O(N) by only remembering the result for previous line (column).

```
Cost[0] = matrix[0, 0]
for x = 1 to m - 1
    Cost[x] = matrix[0, x] + Cost[x-1]
for y = 1 to n - 1
    Cost[0] += matrix[y, 0]
    for x = 1 to m - 1
        Cost[x] = matrix[y, x] + Min(Cost[x-1], Cost[x])
output(Cost[n-1])
```

Don't know how to write in PHP... Here's python sample code

```
matrix = [
    [3, 44, 75],
    [21, 98, 60],
  ]

n = len(matrix)
m = len(matrix[0])

cost = [0] * m

cost[0] = matrix[0][0]
for x in xrange(1, m):
    cost[x] = matrix[0][x] + cost[x-1]
for y in xrange(1, n):
    cost[0] += matrix[y][0]
    for x in xrange(1, m):
        cost[x] = matrix[y][x] + min(cost[x-1], cost[x])

print cost[-1]
```

Comment: The solution suggested you guys are not working. Can you tell me what is the mistake in the code. I have added the code in the question. See edit

Comment: @SkyBuzz sorry, I made a mistake and thought you want `n*n` matrix, and I have a mistake in initializing the first row.